# Access Date/time format using query

Tags: ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007, ado

How can i add the column to the access table with datatype date/time with the format(longtime,shortdate etc)?

I can add a column of type date/time as follows.But it will not set the format for that

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN MyField DateTime
```

So please help so that format for this can be specified in the query.

Comment: What is purpose of doing this?

Comment: I think let user save date in default format and while showing output you can format it.

Comment: I want to store it in that way itself. Anyway there will be query to do it.But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not a query based solution, but is easy to modify properties using a little VBA.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim t As TableDef
Dim f As Field
Dim p

Set db = CurrentDb
Set t = db.TableDefs("myTable")
Set f = t.createField("myDateField", dbDate)
Call t.Fields.Append(f)

Set p = f.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "Long Date")
Call f.Properties.Append(p)
```

I avoided validating if the table, field or property exists since I don't know enough about your actual problem.